# Why was this (admittedly subpar, but working) answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813572/find-special-character-in-string) got deleted fairly quickly by some high-rep users and I'd like to know why.

Before I start defending myself, here's a screenshot:
[image]

Now, I've clicked the [link to the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), but none of the listed reasons for deletion apply to my answer. Yes, it's basically a code-only answer, but it's still an answer that solves the OP's problem. Obviously there's a lot of room for improvement, but that's grounds for an *edit*, not for *deletion*.

---

"Reasons" for deletion that I imagine people will bring up:

- **Code-only answer.** Yes, true, commenting my 2 and a half lines of code would have improved the answer, but anyone who has even a little bit of experience with regex will understand how it works. And if my lack of explanation can make the OP (who thought that `re.match(string.punctuation, word)` would solve his problem and clearly hasn't bothered reading the documentation on `re.match`) go and do some research, then I'll be overjoyed.
- **Rude**. I just know somebody will say my answer was rude, so let me say this: No it's not. I have good reason to believe that OP didn't bother reading the docs. Even if they did, that would mean I was wrong, but not rude. And even if there had been the most obscene collection of slurs in my answer, that problem could've been solved with a simple edit. It wouldn't be a reason to delete code that works perfectly fine. Am I wrong?

Lastly, I'd like to point out that I'm not particularly butthurt about my answer being deleted. I just think it's an answer that didn't deserve to be deleted. If it had been someone else's, I'd have shaken my head in disbelief and voted to undelete it, but since it's my own, I'd really like to know the reason. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: How is this not a code-only answer?

Comment: @ModusTollens code only answer isn't one of the prescribed reasons for deletion anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith No it isn't, but I don't consider code-only answers very useful. Furthermore, answers are not supposed to help the OP only, but other users as well. So not including explanation because of being annoyed at OP for not doing enough research is not the best way of answering.

Comment: @ModusTollens if the code actually works as desired (I don't know Python so can't judge) then a code only answer certainly is potentially useful to someone even though a explanation would make it more generally useful. It is not remotely in the same category as a link only answer where the link has rotted.

Comment: @MartinSmith Of course it's not the best way of answering. But it's no reason to delete the answer.

Comment: I have never claimed that is a reason. The only people that can tell you for sure are the people that voted to delete. I imagine it's because of the snarky paragraph at the end that adds nothing to the answer and just serves to berate the OP. Yes they could have edited it out but they could also decide to vote to delete instead.

Comment: As a moderator, I have never understood how trusted users use their delete votes. I certainly would not have deleted your answer in response to a NAA flag for the reasons you have given.

Comment: @BoltClock - At least one of those delete votes was left by someone who blindly votes to delete anything that appears in the 10k delete votes listing. I don't think they read anything they vote on, and their name regularly seems to be attached to complaints about deleted posts on Meta. Maybe someone should do something about that.

Comment: @Brad Larson: Now I just have to worry about the other two.

Answer (score 7):

The real reason for deletion is that **it doesn't answer the question**.

I could explain why not, but it doesn't look like you even read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) so I won't bother.

Comment: The question looks like *"How can I find out if a string contains anything from string.punctuation?"* In what sense does the code provided not answer the question? Is it incorrect? Or are you saying that wasn't the question? Or it isn't possible for a code only answer to be an answer? Or what?

Comment: I did read the help, so please do elaborate?

Comment: The fact that this answer has 2 upvotes while mine got deleted is actually quite amusing and enlightening. I guess that's probably my answer right there: People are illogical creatures that do illogical things.

Comment: It is Meta, everything is illogical here. Except for the part that's ironic.

Comment: I feel I need to explain something. Compare this answer to mine. I didn't explain my code, but it's reasonable to believe that anyone who knows regex will understand how it works. Even without that, anyone could run the code and confirm that it worked. I also had reason to believe that the OP hadn't looked at the docs. But this answer? It might be right or it might be wrong, I have no way to find out. And the assumption that I haven't read the help is ridiculous, because I _explicitly linked to it in my question_. This answer is __objectively__ and __significantly__ worse than mine.

Comment: Did it even occur to you, @Rawing, that the tone of the comment on the bottom of the answer might have something to do with it?

Comment: @Will Something to do with what? My answer being deleted? Yes. What does that have to do with anything? This answer is still a lot worse than mine.